# Is it possible to generate a Python function with arguments in runtime?

Tags: python

Say,

I have a python function as following:

```
def ooxx(**kwargs):
    doSomething()
    for something in cool:
        yield something
```

I would like to provide another function with named arguments for hints as following:

```
def asdf(arg1, arg2, arg3=1):
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    args, _, _, values = inspect.getargvalues(frame)
    kwargs = dict((key, values[key]) for key in args) # convert args list into dictionary form
    return list(ooxx(**kwargs))
```

Is it possible to have some sort of methods to generate automatically the function "asdf"? I have lots of dynamic generated ooxx functions and I would like to have corresponding asdf functions with customized named arguments. Not sure if this is the correct requirement or right way to coding :p

Comment: Your example code would be easier to follow if you used more meaningful variable names.

Answer (score 4):

Your descriptions doesn't make such sense to me: You wrote a really verbose function that does this:

```
def asdf(arg1, arg2, arg3=1):
    return list(ooxx(**locals()))
```

but you want to inspect the `ooxx` and somehow make up appropriate names for `asdf`s arguments? That is impossible, there is no information about this on `ooxx`.

If you actually *have* a signature and want to create a function from it you would have to resort to `eval` or generate function definitions to a Python file and import it.

There is also the [decorator](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator) module. You can create a function with it like this:

```
import decorator
asdf = decorator.FunctionMaker.create(
                'asdf(arg1, arg2, arg3)', # signature
                'return ooxx(**locals())', # function body
                {'ooxx' : ooxx}, # context for the function
                ('arg3', 1)) # default arguments
```

Comment: Nope. I have already prepared a function generator to generate ooxx1, ooxx2, ooxx3, ..., ooxxN. And I am looking for some sort of function generator to generate asdf1, asdf2, asdf3, ..., asdfN. For each asdfI, the number and name of arguments are different.